# App Install Problems to 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, google-chrome, libreoffice, vmware

Has Ubuntu 13.04 a new set of installation procedures from 12.04, and what are they please?   An install of 13.04 has problems with certain installs of software, all that install correctly to a load of 12.04.

1. Does Google Chrome downloaded from Google install to 13.04, and by what utility please?  Google Chrome installed from the Google site dot deb download file throws error "Dependency is not satisfiable:libudev0(>= 147)", will not install.  The same download installs and functions from 12.04.  Did I make a load error, Is there a package error, or is some different utility needed please?
2. Does Libre Office total package from Ubuntu Software Center install to 13.04, and by what utility please?  Libre Office total package downloaded from Ubuntu software site installs seemingly completely, and seems to operate well, but after installation the 13.04 installer for any subsequent install of any software seems to function well but keeps ending with an error, throwing the error: Errors were encountered while processing: browser-plugin-libreoffice dpkg: error processing browser-plugin-libreoffice (--configure): Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should reinstall it before attempting configuration.  Did I make a load error, Is there a package error, or is some different utility needed please?
3. Does VMWare Player downloaded from VMWare install to 13.04, and by what utility please?  VMWare Player installed from VMWare site dot package download file tries to run from terminal command line "sudo bash vmwarexxxx.package", but fails to start the VMWare installer, instead the license information simply appears in the terminal endlessly looping with keystrokes entered. The same command line used in 12.04 correctly loaded the VMWare installer and VMWare.  Btw, Oracle VM VirtualBox installs and runs correctly on both 12.04 and 13.04.  Did I make a load error, Is there a package error, or is some different utility needed please?

All of the above I have in use on a load of 12.04, working well, only 13.04 seems to throw errors on the install, and of fifty or more apps these are the only three throwing an install error to  date.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed, it works exactly the same. There should be no errors. By simply using Ubuntu Software Center or apt-get install you can install all of the software.

However it seems you didn't upgrade correctly and are facing a lot of issues.

sudo apt-get install -f

Use that to fix several issues with dependencies. You may want to apt-get remove affected packages.

Comment: I agree completely, the installs should be exactly the same, but these three fail as noted on 13.04, but work well on 12.04.  After initially installing 13.04 and fully updating it, I have fully removed and rebooted and then reinstalled Libre Office from Ubuntu Software Center twice, both throwing the same error as noted, the Software Center updater throws the listed error at every use while Libre Office remains installed.  The other two softwares listed failed to install at all, simply throwing errors. Upgrading was done, and removals tried, this to me is a mystery.